# Can one install a C# program that uses `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` into Sharepoint?

Tags: development, client-object-model

I wrote a C# Console Application that uses the Sharepoint `ClientContext` to access SharePoint.

See https://gist.github.com/nddipiazza/d11423323e5febf8175a1c19e892ac9a for the example.

I would like to somehow install this program into Sharepoint so that Site administrators can launch it from Sharepoint web ui. Because about half of my users will want to launch this from Windows, and the other half will want to launch it from Sharepoint.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes it can be done easily. Just depends on what version of SharePoint you are using. If an old version you could create a standard SharePoint web part.

I would go for Jsom instead, its JavaScript equivalent to CSOM so can be easily converted. You could have the jsom code directly within a script editor web part and wouldn't need the authentication code or create a addin if hosted within SharePoint doesn't need authentication otherwise if hosted outside would need auth.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint

Comment: I've already written the code in C#. Does this answer help me do this in C#?

Comment: and i'm using 2013 and 2016 sharepoint

Comment: yes you can do it in C# as a webpart. but you need to add the c# code into the webpart that you make... look here how to make one https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231519(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create a visual web part using visual studio, and deploy it to SharePoint, add web part to a web part from the SharePoint UI.

Example:

**VisualWebPart5.ascx:**

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart5.ascx.cs" Inherits="SharePointProject85.VisualWebPart5.VisualWebPart5" %>
<div id="ListFiles" runat="server"></div>
```

**VisualWebPart5.ascx.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace SharePointProject85.VisualWebPart5
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class VisualWebPart5 : WebPart
    {
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public VisualWebPart5()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetListFiles();
        }

        protected void GetListFiles()
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            html.Append("<p><h2>Web Name: "+web.Title+"</h2></p>");
            //get all lists
            foreach(SPList list in web.Lists){
                html.Append("<p><h4>List Name: " + list.Title + "</h4></p>");
                if (list.RootFolder != null) 
                {
                    //get root folder files of the list
                    foreach (SPFile file in list.RootFolder.Files)
                    {
                        html.Append("<p>Got a file " + file.Name+"</p>");
                    }
                }
            }
            this.ListFiles.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]